# Class associations and multiplicity - UML 2.0 - object oriented

Tags: attributes, uml, class-diagram, multiplicity

I am learning UML and have a practice question I am working on for class diagrams.

I've put together a first version of the diagram but i'm confused about part e. This is the practice question:

[image]

and this is what I have so far:

[image]

Where it says 'Each customer can store a number of debit/credit cards used for payments' does it mean that the customer then has an association with the debit and credit card subclasses? or is the credit card type stored in the customer class as an attribute?

Answer (score 2):

The proposal of Thomas Kilian is not yet the complete solution. You should rename "CreditCard" to "PaymentCard" and make it a union type by partitioning it into the two disjoint subclasses "CreditCard" and "DebitCard". Give the `Customer`-`PaymentCard` association a 1-* multiplicity. Then add a many-to-one association between `Payment` and `PaymentCard`.

Answer (score 1):

It's just that you need an attribute inside `Customer` for a number of credit card numbers. A card number is  less than 2^43. So you can take a (64 bit) integer. Or use a `String` for that.

[image]

The dot-notation says that `card` is an attribute inside `Customer` and since it has a multiplicity not equal one it's an array (or a collection). Vice versa the CreditCard has a unique owner.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. It says "Each customer can store a number of debit/credit cards used for payments".

Comment: Oh yes. My English. "a number of" means a multitude. So you need an array instead. I'll make an update.

Comment: The "exactly one" multiplicity at the `Customer` association end and a few other items (as explained in my answer) are missing.

Comment: @GerdWagner I should have cleaned my glasses :-/ Diagram updated. I did not rename /introduce a general payment card class (left that to the OP).